# Scrapying a form using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After starting learning *Python* I decided to write a web scraping for finding an apartment in a given internet site. This requieres to fill a form with standard questions (e.g. `city`, `max`. `price`, `min`. `number of rooms`, etc.).

The aim is the set my values that I am interesting in the form and to preform scraping on the results.

After starting to analysed the html source code I found that the Internet site have two classes of Tabs

```
<option selected="selected" value="cq144552099594975_tab1" class="tab-trigger">Appartment</option>
<option value="cq144552099594975_tab2" class="tab-trigger">Office</option>

<section class="tab" id="cq144552099594975_tab1">
  <form class="form">
    ...
  </form>
</section>

<section style="display: none;" class="tab" id="cq144552099594975_tab2">
  <form class="form">
    ...
  </form>
</section>
```

From looking at the html source code there are two

```
<form class="form">
```

So far I was able to get the html part of the first class *form* using

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml' )      

form = bsObj.body.form
```

How could I adapt my code to be able to iterate between the two form classes?
Is there a way to print the structure tree of a `BeautifulSoup` object (`bsObj`)?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to scrape the form every time, instead of figuring out the endpoint, creating the appropriate request manually (once), and only scraping the results?

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho, assuming it is not just one internet site i would like to do scrapying, rather then 5. Then each night before it suppose to run I will need to prepare the data...

Comment: If you're scraping multiple websites, aren't the forms different? Either way, you'd figure out the request format once for each site, not once per execution. And I was mostly only curious if there wasn't a simpler way, based on my own experience with scraping real state websites.

Answer (score 1):

For form iteration you could do this:

```
for f in bsObj.body.find_all('form'):
    # All forms in the html
    if 'class' in f and f['class'] == 'form':
        print(f)  # All forms with class="form"
```

As for printing the structure BS objects have .children and .descendants properties which can be used like this:

```
# Print DIRECT children of body
for c in bsObj.body.children:
    print(c)

# Print ALL children of body
for d in bsObj.body.descendants:
    print(d)
```

If you want some quick printing for debugging you can also use .prettify() method like so:

```
print(bsObj.body.form.prettify())
```

Comment: You might want to use the `prettify` function for printing.